# What consequence would there be if $\pi$ was not normal?

Tags: number-theory, pi

It is suspected that $\pi$ is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), that is the distribution of its digits is uniform for any base. Would any results or algorithms, especially those that rely on probabilistic methods, be different if $\pi$ was not normal?

Comment: If $\pi$ is not normal we will have to lock it up in a sanitarium, and all the circles would be lonely and sad.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If $\pi$ has been going around in circles, maybe it should be locked up ? ;-)

Comment: 1) Perhaps, mathematicians would be more careful with accepting unproven hypothesis. But it is very hard indeed to imgaine, how it could be proven that $\pi$ is NOT normal. 2) I do not know any methods relying on the normality of $\pi$